# Disappearing submit button in html5

Tags: html, submit

In the following code, when the output element is present, the submit button is not shown if the browser window is large, but on compressing the window it shows up:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/submit" method="post">
<label for="session_range"> Session Size: </label>
<input id="session_range" type="range" min="1" max="10" 
       value="5" onchange="session_rangevalue.value=value"> 
<output id="session_rangevalue"> 5 </output>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
```

Is this buggy behavior or is there something wrong with the code - I'm testing on Chrome 24.

Comment: Do you have some CSS with it ?

Comment: No, just what's showing in the example.

Comment: And adding a <br> would resolve it. I'm just wondering what's going on.